# Sorting string with its first letter

Tags: c#, string

I have following string

```
string strings = "\"Johnson\", \"Williams\", \"Brown\", \"Jones\"";
```

What I am trying to do is to sort this string alphabetically like this:

- Brown
- Johnson Jones
- Williams

I have no idea what to do and how to solve this. What should I do with it

Comment: You only have one element. `"\"Johnson\", \"Williams\", \"Brown\", \"Jones\""` is a single `string`.

Comment: Yes but I need to sort it!

Comment: So you have a list of strings like this, where you want to split them up, sort them, and recombine them?

Comment: `new List<string>() {"Johnson", "Williams", "Brown", "Jones"}` - here you have 4 strings. you can use `System.Linq`'s `OrderBy` to sort stuff.

Comment: See the answer in the duplicate by "Adbi"

Comment: @Jeremy This question isn't a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar what is the difference to not make it a duplicate? OP is trying to sort a list of strings, I too thought this was primarily "about by first letter" but come to think of it you're going to resort to the second letter or use Distinct with conflicts.

Comment: Look I edited the question. What if it is just a string?

Comment: @Jeremy OP is not trying to sort a list of strings. OP has a "list" of values in a single string that they want to sort. OP will need to split the string up, sort it, and reassemble it.

Comment: @SukhrobKhayitmuradov just do this for the new edit: `List<string> lstStrings = strings.Split(",");`

Comment: @SukhrobKhayitmuradov based on your last edit, you can `strings.Split(',').OrderBy(x => x).ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

You can try *querying* the given string:

- Split on `','` to have separated words
- Get rid of spaces and quotation marks with a help of `Trim()`.
- Order the `word`s
- As I can see you want to `Group` words by the 1st letters
- Finally, lets materialize the result as an array

**Code:**

```
  string strings = "\"Johnson\", \"Williams\", \"Brown\", \"Jones\"";

  string[] result = strings
    .Split(',')
    .Select(word => word.Trim(' ', '"'))
    .Where(word => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
    .OrderBy(word => word)
    .GroupBy(word => word[0])
    .Select(group => string.Join(" ", group))
    .ToArray();
```

If you want to obtain `string` instead of array, put `Join`:

```
  string myString = string.Join(" ", result);
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
Brown
Johnson Jones
Will
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach with `Split` and `Join`

```
string strings = "\"Johnson\", \"Williams\", \"Brown\", \"Jones\"";
string result = string.Join(", ", strings.Split().Select(x => x.Trim(',')).OrderBy(x => x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a list with multiple strings, we can use a bubble sorting algorithm to sort the list.

Loop through the list swapping positions if the second string has a lower letter than the first one. Loop until the list is fully sorted.